# Groovy: Writing an xml document results in an encoding error

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to update a very large xml document, more than 72,000 lines long, with groovy. I can parse the file correctly and edit it okay, but the output is corrupt when I try to open it in a browser (the input file is able to be viewed in a browser).

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1401 at column 5: Encoding error Below is a rendering of
>   the page up to the first error.

This is line 1401:

```
<ENTRY MODIFIED_DATE="2013/9/9" MODIFIED_TIME="59764" AUDIO_ID="a very long string" 
TITLE="Sea Lo Que Sea Será (Original Mix)" ARTIST="Above And Beyond Feat. Miguel Bosé">
```

When I go to that line everything appears normal so I am guessing the problem is somewhere else in the file.

This is how I am writing the output xml file:

```
new File("C:/workspacGROOVY/org.something.groovy/collection_out.xml").withWriter { out ->
    out << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.xmlDeclaration() }
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(out)).print(xml)
}
```

Disclaimer: This is the first thing I've written in groovy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying UTF-8 as the encoding:

```
new File("C:/workspacGROOVY/org.something.groovy/collection_out.xml").withWriter('UTF-8') { out ->
    out << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.xmlDeclaration() }
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(out)).print(xml)
}
```

see [this post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/11/groovy-goodness-readers-and-writers.html) for a smaller example.

Comment: Thank you! How do I add  "standalone="no"" as well?

Comment: @user2643192 I thought `mkp.xmlDeclaration( standalone:'no' )` should do it (but I can't get it to work)...  `mkp.pi( xml:[ version:'1.0', standalone:'no' ] )` seems to work though...

Comment: Thanks to [Steve](https://code-dojo.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-groovy-markupbuilder-to-generate.html?showComment=1593518864741#c7477466496883352700)
I manage to add the `standalone: ’no’` with his way, still a mystery to me though.